# JLable not showing up

Tags: java

```
public OpenFrame() {

    openFrame = new JFrame();

    loadButton.setBounds(150, 100, 150, 100);
    loadButton.addActionListener(this);
    loadButton.setText("Load Data");
    loadButton.setFocusable(false);
    loadButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    resetButton.setBounds(150, 220, 150, 100);
    resetButton.addActionListener(this);
    resetButton.setText("Reset Data");
    resetButton.setFocusable(false);
    resetButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));

    welcomeMessage = new JLabel("Hello there! Welcome back. Choose an option below:");
    welcomeMessage.setVerticalTextPosition(TOP);
    welcomeMessage.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    openFrame.setTitle("BudgetPlanner");
    openFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    openFrame.setResizable(false);
    openFrame.setLayout(null);
    openFrame.add(welcomeMessage);
    openMessage();
    openFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    openFrame.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    openFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    openFrame.add(loadButton);
    openFrame.add(resetButton);
    openFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

My `JLabel` is not being displayed on the screen. On this screen, I want my Label texts and two buttons to be displayed. Where did I go wrong?

p.s. please ignore the openMessage(); code in between!

Comment: Stop using setBounds and move to [layoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you never set the bounds of the `JLabel`. Try setting the (x, y) coordinates to the desired location and it should work.

However, you also have other issues with regards to how you are adding components to the `JFrame`. For starters, **never add components directly into the frame**. Add the components to a panel and then add the panel to the frame's context pane. Also, **never nullify the JFrame's layout manager**.

I added the `setBounds` call on the label and worked for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame openFrame = new JFrame();

    JButton loadButton = new JButton();
    loadButton.setBounds(150, 100, 150, 100);
//    loadButton.addActionListener(this);
    loadButton.setText("Load Data");
    loadButton.setFocusable(false);
    loadButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));

    JButton resetButton = new JButton();
    resetButton.setBounds(150, 220, 150, 100);
//    resetButton.addActionListener(this);
    resetButton.setText("Reset Data");
    resetButton.setFocusable(false);
    resetButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));

    JLabel welcomeMessage = new JLabel("Hello there! Welcome back. Choose an option below:");
    welcomeMessage.setBounds(150, 50, 300, 30); // You were missing this
    welcomeMessage.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
    welcomeMessage.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    openFrame.setTitle("BudgetPlanner");
    openFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    openFrame.setResizable(false);
    openFrame.setLayout(null);
    openFrame.add(welcomeMessage);
//    openMessage();
    openFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    openFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    openFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    openFrame.add(loadButton);
    openFrame.add(resetButton);
    openFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image]

---

The correct way should be something like this

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
// set the size and other properties on the panel
...
// create the components and set their properties, like bounds.
pane.add(label);
pane.add(resetButton);
pane.add(loadButton);
...
// create JFrame and set it's properties.
openFrame.setContentPane(pane);
```

Comment: Oh it worked fine for me as well! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JLabel have bonds

```
 welcomeMessage.setBounds(150, 50, 300, 30);
```

Then create the JPanel then add your JLabel inside JPanel you created.

```
JPanel myNewPanel = new JPanel();
pane.add(label);
```

Finally add your pane inside your JFrame.

```
add(myNewPanel);
```